# Parsec: Parsing a list of lists, both with the same delimiter

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Consider a simple language that's a list of space-delimited commands. Each command takes a single letter as the command name, and a series of space-delimited numbers as its arguments; e.g. `a 1 2 3 b 4 5 6 d 7 e f` would represent the following commands:

- **a** 1 2 3
- **b** 4 5 6
- **d** 7
- **e**
- **f**

The problem is that it keeps grabbing items through `sepBy`, and reaches for another number but fails when it gets to "b".

However, this yields the following error when passed through the code below:

```
Left "error" (line 1, column 5):
unexpected "b"
expecting space
```

I realize now that this is likely coming from an error in the way I'm looking at the problem, and would appreciate someone pointing out how to parse something like this.

---

```
module Main where

import Control.Applicative hiding (many, optional, (<|>))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Numeric (readSigned, readFloat)

commands = command `sepBy` spaces

command = do
  l <- letter
  ns <- number `sepBy` spaces
  return (l, ns)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ show $ parse commands "error" "a 1 2 3 b 4 5 6 d 7 e f"

number :: CharParser () Double
number = do s <- getInput
            case readSigned readFloat s of
              [(n, s')] -> n <$ setInput s'
              _         -> empty
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try consuming the spaces after each non-space token. E.g.

```
commands = many (command <* spaces)

command = do
  l <- letter
  spaces
  ns <- many (number <* spaces)
  return (l, ns)
```

Or

```
command = (,) <$> (letter <* spaces) <*> many (number <* spaces)
```

The main idea is: after you parse something, the next character should be a non-space starting the next item to be parsed.

Comment: I came to the same realization; the same can be achieved by using `sepEndBy` instead of `sepBy`.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the parser as @chi has suggested.

The deal with `sepBy` is that if the separator is matched then `sepBy` expects to parse another item.